# How do I process this data with a regex in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a database dump, looking like this:

> ;i:23;s:18:"Product Name1";i:24;s:27:"Product Name2";i:25;s:15:"Product Name3"; [...]

All I'd like to get in Notepad++ is this:

> Product Name1,Product Name2,Product Name3

What regex should I use for search and replace in Notepad++? The closest I've gotten is `^"."$` but this does not find the string.

Comment: what have you tired ? You wont find people very helping if you don't show some effort on your part

Comment: This is the first time I try to use it... now learning it from http://regexone.com/lesson/5? but I need quick help. Anyway, if this is the rule here, I'll try to get a solution myself :)

Comment: Tried this all character between the quotation marks ^"."$ but this one does not include the " and does not find the string

Comment: That's because you're matching the whole line with one char in quotes...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Find (check Regular Expressions): `i:\d+;s:\d+:"([\w\s]+)";`

and Replace with: `\1,`